# Converting string from base 16 to 36 gives same result for all values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with more than a million rows and growing with a unique CHAR(40) hash string in base 16 encoding. To save space I want to convert them to base 36 encoding, but I am running into a problem. I use `UPDATE tokens SET hash = CONV(`hash`, 16, 36);` to do a mass update.

But it returns with: `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '3W5E11264SGSF' for key 'PRIMARY'`

If I then check my table by running `SELECT hash, CONV(hash, 16, 36) as conv FROM tokens;` I notice all of the CONV functions return '3W5E11264SGSF'.

```
'70b35c8642114cd056077f180a8ebe6e0a28ad61', '3W5E11264SGSF'
'70b38395682af39061e377852853760807641175', '3W5E11264SGSF'
'70b3984a50e3e6d1cac4536692ac06c6f1353df8', '3W5E11264SGSF'
```

Can anyone help me by telling me what is going wrong? Or provide me with a solution to my problem.

Comment: I am using backticks, but I couldn't figure out how I add them without stopping and starting the code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is: too high values. `'3W5E11264SGSF'` is, in terms of integer data type, `18446744073709551615`:

```
mysql> SELECT CONV('3W5E11264SGSF', 36, 10);
+-------------------------------+
| CONV('3W5E11264SGSF', 36, 10) |
+-------------------------------+
| 18446744073709551615          |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And that's limit for MySQL [`BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) data type. Yes: [`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) uses integer operations under the hood and can not exceed this value, it's a restriction. To overcome, you have two options:

- Implement the logic in application. So: select value for certain row, make conversion in your application, then write it back to database
- Create your own conversion function which will operate on string values, so do not rely on integer operations. Options are - create [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html) or user-land [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html) syntax.

It may seem strange, that MySQL will return limit-value when overflow happened (personally, I would prefer it will return `NULL` and produce overflow warning), but that's as it is now. To illustrate:

```
mysql> SELECT CONV('18446744073709551615', 10, 36);
+--------------------------------------+
| CONV('18446744073709551615', 10, 36) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 3W5E11264SGSF                        |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONV('18446744073709551616', 10, 36);
+--------------------------------------+
| CONV('18446744073709551616', 10, 36) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 3W5E11264SGSF                        |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And so on - that is why you'll get duplicate if use that value as unique sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much. Did not realize the BIGINT limit would be the problem.

Comment: Please. someone could edit this answer to fix broken link to "UDF" in mysql doc